# XMLDocument (via jQuery ajax call) stored as string in localStorage results in Safari not finding title elements

Tags: jquery, safari, local-storage

I've run into an interesting issue that I'm afraid might be a bug with Safari, or something I'm just not seeing.

I have a static XML file with a number of 'game' elements. Within each of these is a 'title' element, amongst others.

I pull the XML file via jQuery's ajax method, passing dataType of text, and then store the result in localStorage.

If I then pull this data out of localStorage and parse it via jQuery I can successfully parse all elements within the XML on IE 9, Chrome 10, Opera 11, Firefox 4. However, in Safari 5 and Safari current for iPod Touch and iPad (both at current version), all elements are output with the *exception of* the title element's text (within the XML).

**Edit**: This same behavior occurs if I change the element from 'title' to 'Title' as well as 'Name.' If I change it to something like 'xName' then the information pulls in just fine, so my code appears to be okay.

Relevant jQuery call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/xml/video_games.xml",
        dataType: 'text', // We'll grab it as text, so we can save it into localStorage
        success: function (data) {
            videoGameXml = data;
            localStorage['VideoGameXml'] = videoGameXml;
            addDataToPage(videoGameXml);
        }
    });
});
```

addDataToPage:

```
function addDataToPage(data) {
    $('#MainData').hide();
    var htmlOutput = "<ol>";
    try {
        $(videoGameXml).find("game").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('addOn') != "true" && $(this).find('own').text() == "yes") {
                // Displays console and version elements, but not the title.
                htmlOutput += "<li><strong>" + $(this).find('title').text() + "</strong> for the " + $(this).find("console").text() + " " + $(this).find("version").text() + "</li>";
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        JamesRSkemp.dumpObject(e);
    }
    htmlOutput += "</ol>";
    $('#MainData').html(htmlOutput);
    $('#MainData').show();
}
```

If I revert back and skip the localStorage step then the titles display correctly. However, that's not much help, since the purpose of the page is to be available *offline*, and I'd rather use what's supported with all current browsers.

I'm also pulling from a static XML file, so changing the data to JSON would have to be done on the page, or I'd have to setup a service to parse the XML and return JSON. I'm not against doing one or other if I need to, but ... I'd rather change the element name.

I'm also not against storing the output HTML to localStorage, instead of the XML data, but I'd much rather have everything in the XML available, instead of just what I choose to output at the moment (for additional features down the road).

You can see a working version of this at http://media.jamesrskemp.com/xmlHtml/video_gamesSO.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this - [Interesting feature with parsing XML with jQuery on Safari](http://strivinglife.com/words/post/Interesting-feature-with-parsing-XML-with-jQuery-on-Safari.aspx) - but basically instead of the following:

```
$(videoGameXml).find("game").each(...);
```

I needed to have:

```
$($.parseXML(videoGameXml)).find("game").each(
```

Safari requires that extra bit of code to correctly parse the string as XML.